# makefile target without paying attention to modification time

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want a rule that creates any of its prerequisities but ignores their modification times. Is it possible?

Here is why I need this: I have a makefile for creating openssl certificate authority and signing requests. Signing the certificates requires the PRESENCE of the file index.txt (and two others but that's not relevant).

My rules would read:

```
index.txt:
    touch $@

CA.crt: CA.csr CA.key index.txt
    openssl ca .... -updatedb ....

%.crt: %.csr
    openssl ca .... -updatedb ....
```

CA.crt depends on PRESENCE of index.txt because openssl doesn't create it if it doesn't exist. Now, whenever I try to:

```
make whatever.crt
```

`index.txt` is updated and `CA.crt` is rebuild again next make run.

One solution is:

```
CA.crt: CA.csr CA.key
    $(MAKE) index.txt
    openssl ca ....
```

but perhaps there is a proper elegant way to do it correctly. Is it?

UPDATE: I need something that is the exact opposite of .PHONY. I need a target that once generated is never recreated again. I hope now the question is clear(er).

Answer (score 2):

So you want a "create unless already exists" target. Why not place that logic in the recipe?

```
target: prereq1 prereq2
        if test -r "$@"; then \
           touch "$@"; \
        else \
           **your rule to create target here**; \
        fi
```

The touch branch part is optional but may speed up things minimally for further runs. In addition, it will cause `make` to consider `target` up-to-date with respect to prereq1 and 2. Any well-written makefile should respond with `nothing to do` when there is nothing to do.

Comment: But I need the exact opposite of .PHONY

I need something that is never recreated once it exists.
(I edited the question to make it clear).

Comment: @ChewbaccaKL Ok, I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Jens, thanks for your answer. It almost works. Almost, because touching $@ would make it newer than other targets and other targets will be remade next run.

I would consider running

    touch --date="2000-01-01" $@ 

but this is not an elegant solution, I think.

Running

    $(MAKE) -q index.txt

as the first command is more elegant (although it runs make unnecessarily) but the rule

   @test -r index.txt  || $(MAKE) index.txt

looks even worse.

Perhaps we need to define

    define assure_index_exists()
    [ -r index.txt ] && make -q index.txt; enddef

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html).

> Occasionally, however, you have a situation where you want to impose a specific ordering on the rules to be invoked without forcing the target to be updated if one of those rules is executed. In that case, you want to define order-only prerequisites.

```
index.txt:
    touch $@

CA.crt: CA.csr CA.key | index.txt
    openssl ca .... -updatedb ....

%.crt: %.csr
    openssl ca .... -updatedb ....
```